# css seems to not work properly when i use .htaccess to make 'pretty links'

Tags: php, html, css, .htaccess

i am practicing on making pretty links.
i have this page:
http://news.red-sec.net/article/26/This-is-a-title
it works perfectly, the original page for it is
article.php?id=26&title=This-is-a-title //sorry can't post more than 2 links according to stack overflow

Fortunately they both work the same.
I tried doing the same for user/usernamehere:
http://red-sec.net/user/badboy17 <-- the style of the page seems like it cut through half of it.
the original page is
user.php?u=badboy17 //sorry again (this page works as i want it to) 
here is the code for the user.php page:

```
    <?php
    ini_set('session.cookie_domain', '.red-sec.net');
    session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', '.red-sec.net');
    session_start();
    include 'res/connection.php';
    include 'res/menu.php';
    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <title>R3D S3C | Home page</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style1.css"/>
      <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php menu(); ?>
    <?php 
    if(isset($_GET['u'])){
        $user = $_GET['u'];
        $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$user'";
        $r = mysqli_query($connect,$query);
        $num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($r);
        echo $num_rows;
        if($num_rows < '1'){
            header('Location: index.php');
        }else{
            $row = mysqli_fetch_array($r);
            $username = $row['username'];
            $email = $row['email'];
            echo "<h2 class='title'>$username</h2>";
        }
    }else{
        header('Location: http://red-sec.net');
    }
    ?>
    <?php endbd(); ?>
    </body>
    </html>
```

code for menu.php where both functions menu() and endbd() are:

```
<?php
require 'connection.php';
function menu(){
  if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])){
  echo '<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top shadow">
    <div class="container">
      <a href="http://red-sec.net" class="navbar-brand">Red-Sec.net</a>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="menuitem"><a href="http://red-sec.net">Home</a></li>
        <li class="menuitem"><a href="http://announcements.red-sec.net">Announcements</a></li>
        <li class="menuitem"><a href="http://forum.red-sec.net">Forum</a></li>
        <li class="menuitem"><a href="http://blog.red-sec.net">Blog</a></li>
        <li class="menuitem"><a href="http://news.red-sec.net">News</a></li>
        <li class="menuitem"><a href="http://donate.red-sec.net">Donate</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="menuitem"><a href="http://red-sec.net/signup.php">Sign Up</a></li>
        <li class="menuitem"><a href="http://red-sec.net/Login.php">Log In</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <script
    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"
    integrity="sha256-16cdPddA6VdVInumRGo6IbivbERE8p7CQR3HzTBuELA="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src=" ../js/menu.js"></script>
  <div class="container bg">
  <div class="row full">
  <div class="col-lg-8 bd">';
}else{
  $username = $_SESSION['username'];
  echo '<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top shadow">
    <div class="container">
      <a href="http://red-sec.net" class="navbar-brand">Red-Sec.net</a>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="menuitem"><a href="http://red-sec.net">Home</a></li>
        <li class="menuitem"><a href="http://announcements.red-sec.net">Announcements</a></li>
        <li class="menuitem"><a href="http://forum.red-sec.net">Forum</a></li>
        <li class="menuitem"><a href="http://blog.red-sec.net">Blog</a></li>
        <li class="menuitem"><a href="http://news.red-sec.net">News</a></li>
        <li class="menuitem"><a href="http://donate.red-sec.net">Donate</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="menuitem"><a href="http://red-sec.net/profile.php">'.$username.'</a></li>
        <li class="menuitem"><a href="http://red-sec.net/Logout.php">Log Out</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <script
    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"
    integrity="sha256-16cdPddA6VdVInumRGo6IbivbERE8p7CQR3HzTBuELA="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="../js/menu.js"></script>
  <div class="container bg">
  <div class="row full">
  <div class="col-lg-8 bd">';
}
}
function endbd(){
    require'connection.php';
  echo '</div>
  <div class="col-lg-4 bd sidebar stick">
  <h2 class="title" style="margin-left:0%!important;">Latest News Posts</h2>
<hr class="under">';
$query = "SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 5";
$run = mysqli_query($connect,$query);
if(!$run){
    echo 'sorry';
}
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($run)){
  $article_id = $row['article_id'];
  $user_id = $row['user_id'];
  $title = $row['title'];
  $content = $row['content'];
  $date = $row['date'];
  $query = "SELECT username FROM users WHERE ID = '$user_id'";
  $test = mysqli_query($connect,$query);
  $row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($test);
  $user_name = $row2['username'];
  $title2 = str_replace(" ","-",$title);
  echo '<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12"><h3 class="para"><a class="para" href="http://news.red-sec.net/article/'.$article_id.'/'.$title2.'">'.$title.'</a></h3>
  <p class="para">Written by: '.$user_name.'</p>
  </div>
  </div>';
  }
  echo '</div>
  </div>
  </div>';
}
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the css directory is in the root directory try this...

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/style1.css"/>
```

so, this tells the browser to look for root directory `/` and then the css directory within that. Without that forward slash the browser is looking for a relative link, eg; trying to find a css directory within the directory of the current page, and since you rewrite those, it doesn't find a css directory.

Comment: u sir do magic, thank you so much it worked :) i am a noobie at this and it works so thanks a lot

Comment: relative verses absolute URLs is something that has bit us all at some point. Don't feel bad and I am far from a magician, just been there, done that is all